# I want to call images from database in to ASP:repeater control but I am getting <image src"System.Byte[]"> in result

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

This is my code in aspx file

```
cnn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from carousel", cnn);
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    da1.Fill(dt1);
    Rp1.DataSource = dt1;
    Rp1.DataBind();
cnn.Close();
```

and this is repeater

```
<asp:Repeater id="Rp1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="item">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' runat="server" />
        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <footertemplate></footertemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I tried everything but I am getting  in result every time I really want some help on this, I am new to ASP.Net

Comment: check this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx
you can also make some ashx handler for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the value coming from the database is a byte array representing the actual data of the image.  Whereas the `src` of an `img` tag expects a URL to an image.  There are essentially two ways to go about this...

1. Create a separate page (or ASHX handler preferably) which returns *only* the data for the image (no HTML or anything like that) and link to that page.
2. Base-64 encode the byte array and include that as a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in the `src` attribute.

There are lots of tutorials for the first option online.  [This one](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) was found by a quick Google search, there are others as well.  Essentially what the handler would do is accept an identifier on the query string, use that identifier to get the image from the database, then write the appropriate headers and content to the response.  The URL for the `src` attribute would then be that handler.  Something like:

```
ImageUrl='<# "~/handler.ashx?id=" + Eval("id") #>'
```

(Or whatever your data-bound data uses as an identifier for the image.)

Comment: I didn't get this, I created on ASHX handler file but I don't know what to write in it to get images from Database Table. I saw your example but it didn't helped much. Please Help me with the ASHX file.

Comment: @user1679944: Essentially, the code in your ASHX handler would be doing the same thing your original code was doing... fetching the image from the database.  But instead of trying to set that image as a `src` attribute on an `img` element, it just writes the image data directly to the response.  The reason for this is because an HTML page and an image referenced by that page are *two* separate requests.  You have a page for the first request (the HTML page), the handler should service the second request (the image).

Comment: But now I am having trouble with binding data to repeater from ASHX file.

Comment: @user1679944: The ASHX file doesn't have a repeater, or anything to do with a repeater.  It just returns an image, nothing more.  The repeater in your main page would bind that `ImageUrl` property as the URL of the ASHX handler.  So, for example, if you have 10 records in the repeater then you would have a total of 11 requests.  One to the page, where the repeater shows 10 `img` tags each with a URL to the ASHX handler (and 10 different IDs).  This results in 10 requests to the ASHX handler, one for each image.

Comment: This is a very good answer, David. I think it clears things up (at least for me) in terms of what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your image column name in database "ImageName" then

Solution 1:if your image in Root Folder

```
 <img src='<%#Eval("ImageName")%>' alt="" />

OR



 <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageName")%>' runat="server" />
```

Solution 2:if your image in images Folder

```
<img src='<%# "images/" + Eval("ImageName") %>'  alt=""/>
```

OR

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# "images/" + Eval("ImageName") %>' runat="server" />
```

Your Final Solution:

```
<asp:Repeater id="Rp1" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="item">
<img src='<%#Eval("ImageName")%>' alt="" />
OR
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# "images/" + Eval("ImageName") %>' runat="server" />
        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <footertemplate></footertemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  to convert in URI for IMG HTML tag:

```
<img src="<%# System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Eval("bynarydatacolumn")) %>" />
```

or equivalent.